# Finding the interval between demands in an excel forecasting sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, forecasting, vba

I want to find a way for Excel to automatically give me the following 'interval':

```
Month      1 2 3 4 5 6 
Demand     1 0 0 1 0 1 
'Interval' 0 0 0 3 0 2
```

The 'interval' shows the amount of months between the demands. Is this doable in some sort of way? I couldnt find a function in Excel to do this. Maybe there is a way in VBA? I need this for the CROSTON forecasting method.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort!

J. Rommers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the number of consecutive zeros in the row above and adjust.  In **B3** enter:

```
=IF(B2=0,0,COUNTIF($B$2:B2,"=0")-SUM($A$3:A3))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 3 columns are A, B and C use:

```
=MATCH(1,Bn:B1,0)-1
```

where Bn its the n of C